# How to find duplicated data group in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, duplicates

Assume that I have a simple table like this:

```
  f1   |   f2
--------------
   a   |   b
   b   |   a
   a   |   c
   c   |   a
   a   |   d
   d   |   a
```

`f1` and `f2` both are similar in nature and it doesn't matter the order of relation between them. I mean if i say a is related with b, so b is related with a

I need to find duplicated relations and remove them. in this example `(a,b) , (a,c) , (a,d)` **OR** `(b,a) , (c,a) , (d,a)` , one of these three records sets should be looked up and removed.

Anyone please give me a query which finds duplicated data group.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists` to exhibit "mirror" records:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.f1 = t.f2 and t1.f2 = t.f1)
```

If you want one of the duplicates only, then:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.f1 < t.f2 
    and exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.f1 = t.f2 and t1.f2 = t.f1)
```

Comment: `where (t1.f1, t1.f2) = (t.f2, t.f1)` is invalid expression in oracle and cause to raise `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

Comment: I tried with `where (t1.f1=t.f2 and t1.f2=t.f1)` but unfortunately it results whole the records in `mytable`

Comment: @AliAdlavaran: that's because all records in your table actually are "mirrored" by some other record... Which result do you actually want?

Comment: Yes, all the relations are mirrored. I need to have just `(a,b) , (a,c) , (a,d)` 3 records as result

Comment: @AliAdlavaran: just add one more condition in the `where` clause: `where f1 < f2 and exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.f1 = t.f2 and t1.f2 = t.f1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EXISTS` and `GREATER THAN` operator as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
     WHERE T1.F1 = T.F2
       AND T1.F2 = T.F1
)
AND T1.F1 > T1.F2;
```

If you want to remove such duplicate records then use `DELETE` instead of `SELECT *` in above query.

Comment: Hey Tejash, congrats for the `oracle` gold badge!